# How to change all value in object to an shorter object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want change all value in an object javascript (object in array) to an shorter object (only get 2 last number), like this:

```
const arr = [
    {
        number_1: 568, 
        number_2: 45462, 
        number_3: 9861254,
        number_4: 45543321
    }
]
```

to:

```
const arr = [
    {
        number_1: 68, 
        number_2: 62, 
        number_3: 54,
        number_4: 21
    }
]
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: You can loop through the objects in the array and through each key in the object and modify them. What difficulty are you facing in achieveing this?

Comment: Those look like numbers, not strings, so it'd be `% 100`

Comment: @Nitheesh I'm a newbie to Javascript, so it's quite difficult for me. Sorry if it makes you feel like a silly question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const arr = [
    {
        number_1: 568, 
        number_2: 45462, 
        number_3: 9861254,
        number_4: 45543321
    }
]

console.log(arr.map(item => {
  const clone = {...item};
  for(let key in clone) {
    clone[key] = parseInt(clone[key].toString().slice(-2));
  }
  return clone;
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
const arr = [
    {
        number_1: 568, 
        number_2: 45462, 
        number_3: 9861254,
        number_4: 45543321
    }
]

const arrNew = [];
for(let i in arr){
    arrNew[i] = {}
 for(let key of Object.keys(arr[i])){
    arrNew[i][key] = +arr[i][key].toString().slice(-2);
 }
}
```